# RISC-V 32b Simulation with Spike

Tags: gcc, simulation, riscv

Has anyone used spike/pk in 32-bit mode?

```
$ riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -g -m32 -march=RV32IM -DRISCV test.c test
$ spike --isa=RV32 pk test
assertion failed @ 0x000052bc: ntohl(hdr->magic) == FDT_MAGIC
```

The initial build.sh install didn't provide a 32b version of pk, so I used riscv32-unknown-

elf-gcc to cross-compile pk for the 32b RISC-V target processor as follows:

```
$ ../configure --prefix=$RISCV/riscv32-unknown-elf --host=riscv32-unknown-elf
$ make XLEN=32
$ make install
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can check something...

1. try to "spike --isa=RV32IM" command line.
2. pk must be compiled with RV32IM instruction only.
3. your assertion message seems... related to device-tree feature. so, you can

   - check whether device-tree blob is right or not.
   - roll-back your pk and spike to the version that device-tree feature is not included.

Comment: pk cannot compile with RV32IM instruction set (there are unknown instructions in the .S files). pk can compile with RV32IMA and RV64IMA. 

"spike --isa=RV32IM" didn't change anything in my testing

Reverted to an old build (summer 2015). At that time spike did not support --isa configuration and successfully runs our 32b test program even though pk was compiled in 64b, i.e. "spike pk64 test32" worked.